# Sitecore WFFM checkbox values on Create Item

Tags: sitecore

I'm using the Create Item save action in a web form. I have a checkbox list that points to a folder containing category items. This is mapped to a Multilist field on the item template that it will create when the user submits the form. But it's passing the checkbox text, not the value, so the multilist for each new item created has bad data in it. Does anyone know how to set the checkbox list to pass the values instead? I'm kind of surprised it's doing this in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't had a chance to test this, but theoretically, you could create a new field type that inherits from `CheckboxList`, and let's say we call it `CheckboxListPipedValues`. The code would look something like this:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Sitecore.Form.Core.Controls.Data;
using Sitecore.Form.Web.UI.Controls;

public class CheckboxListPipedValues : Sitecore.Form.Web.UI.Controls.CheckboxList
{
    [Browsable(false)]
    public override ControlResult Result
    {
        get
        {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder1 = new StringBuilder();
            var checkedItems = this.InnerListControl.Items.Where(a => a.Selected).ToList();
            var values = string.Join("|", checkedItems.Select(c => c.Value));
            foreach (var item in checkedItems)
            {
                stringBuilder1.AppendFormat("{0}, ", item.Text);
            }
            return new ControlResult(this.ControlName, values, stringBuilder1.ToString(0, (stringBuilder1.Length > 0 ? stringBuilder1.Length - 2 : 0)));
        }
    }
}
```

In Sitecore, simply go to `/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Field Types/List Types/Checkbox List` and duplicate that item. Then change the assembly and class to the new control. Change your form to use the new field, and ensure that the values are mapped properly. Now the output of the value should be a pipe separated list of the values which should work nicely with the multilist field.

**EDIT:**
For MVC, it's the same process, but you'll need to update the `MVC Type` in the field type item to point to your new class.  The code for MVC should look something like this:

```
using Sitecore.Data;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.Form.Core.Controls.Data;
using Sitecore.Forms.Core.Data;
using Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Data.TypeConverters;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Mvc;


public class CheckBoxListPipedField : CheckBoxListField 
{
    public CheckBoxListPipedField(Item item) : base(item)
    {
    }

    public override ControlResult GetResult()
    {
        var values = new List<string>();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder1 = new StringBuilder();
        if (this.Items != null)
        {
            foreach (SelectListItem selectListItem in
                from item in this.Items
                where item.Selected
                select item)
            {
                values.Add(selectListItem.Value);
                stringBuilder1.AppendFormat("{0}, ", selectListItem.Text);
            }
        }
        var results = string.Join("|", values);
        return new ControlResult(base.ID.ToString(), base.Title, results, stringBuilder1.ToString(0, (stringBuilder1.Length > 0 ? stringBuilder1.Length - 2 : 0)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I think that will work, but I'm using MVC so I need to make some changes to that code. I'm having some trouble with selecting checkedItems. If you have any suggestion on how to re-write it for MVC I'd appreciate it!

Comment: @JasonDavidson, I added the MVC version.  Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Ok, almost there. 2 things: Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Data.TypeConverters doesn't exist. Should it be TypeProviders? And when I build it I get the following error: Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Models.Fields.CheckBoxListField does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments.

Comment: You should be able to add a constructor as updated above.  As for the `TypeConverters`, I took the using statements from a Sitecore 8 dll.. you might be able to safely remove the using statement. If not, let me know what version of Sitecore you're on and I'll get the appropriate updates.

Comment: That's exactly what I did and it's working! Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @JasonDavidson, Awesome, my pleasure. Please be sure to mark this as the answer if it all worked out.