# Sitecore / WFFM : Text is stored instead the value

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I've created a register page with WFFM(8.0 rev. 141217) in Sitecore ( Sitecore 8 Update 2)
I have a list of cities that the user can pick. ( dropdownlist )
I picked a certain field to be the text-value and a field to be the value-value.

When the user completes the form the text-value is stored to the profile-field, i need this to be the value-value.

Is this behaviour to be expected or did something go wrong ?

Edit: Added image

The postal code is what is shown in the Droplist.
But it is also the value that is saved to the user profile field.
[image]

Comment: For our reference, can you add an image of the Dialog where you select the text and values fields for the drop down list

Comment: Possibly due to a genuine issue in Sitecore. What save action are you using to enter the values into the User's profile?

Comment: I believe I answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30767265/4897782